# Python to update Google Sheets

Tags: python, json, url, google-sheets

i would like to update my google sheet using this code:

```
import requests
snav_timetable_url = "https://statusinvest.com.br/acao/getearnings?IndiceCode=ibovespa&Filter=&Start=1991-12-31&End=2021-05-07"
r = requests.get(snav_timetable_url).json()

snav_timetable_data_cleaned = []
for datecom in r["dateCom"]:
    print(f"{datecom['code']}\t{datecom['resultAbsoluteValue']}\t{datecom['dateCom']}\t{datecom['paymentDividend']}\t{datecom['earningType']}\t{datecom['dy']}\t{datecom['recentEvents']}\t{datecom['recentEvents']}\t{datecom['uRLClear']}")
```

Like This:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTNWN1ylkgv68Vk1I8Snb-SyBKtOxO5HH5P-JFcaR3oxQlyqBb3740Bu9rpbLrnE_w5Y1IwF3DwQRCY/pubhtml

But i can't find out how.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: This should help you get started. https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python

Comment: I want to put the information scrapped by the code into a google sheet. With all the columms and all the rows of the python code.